# FCM: How to avoid duplicate notifications if a user has subscribed to multiple topics

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, subscribe

Say User A has subscribed to Topics T1, T2 and T3.

If I send same notification to Topics T1 and T3. Will A receives two notifications ?

If So, how to avoid this duplicate notifications ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send your notifications to multiple topics at once as shown in firebase documentation:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "condition": "'dogs' in topics || 'cats' in topics",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
  }
}
```

More details here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is limited to only 5 topics. Is there any way to send to more than 5 topics without sending duplicates?